# angular-ui-calendar error: 'calendar.fullCalendar is not a function'

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

this is in the directive.

Have been pounding my brains out for days on this

angular 1.4.7
angular-ui-calendar 1.0.1
fullcalendar 2.3.1 2.4.0 etc
jquery 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.1

any one else running into this??

Comment: Is your problem is fixed after including moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

You don't list moment.js as one of your dependent scripts, but it is required by full calendar.

I created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yX7oCa?p=preview) just to try this out and I did indeed get the error, but you'll note right above the error you mentioned it complains about moment not being available.

[image]

You haven't given me much to go on, but since you didn't mention moment in your dependent scripts that's the best guess I can come up with. If you remove the comment tags that surround the moment.js script in index.html in the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yX7oCa?p=preview) I provided, it will render the calendar.

```
    <!-- 
    <script data-require="moment.js@2.10.2" data-semver="2.10.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    -->
```